# GAE Full Text Search, find exact match

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

Using the GAE Experimental Full Text Search how can I search for something e.g. "car" without getting results where "car" is part of sentence. 
So basically I want to find the exact match based on a keyword.

Thanks!

Comment: Where would you find "car" _except_ in a sentence?

Comment: Lets say I have one field with the word "car" and another field with the sentence "This is my car". If I then search for the keyword "car" how can I only retrieve the field containing "car", that is the exact match?

Comment: Don't use the fulltext search API - just use a standard indexed field in a datastore model.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to do, but you might take a look at field type `AtomField` : a string which is treated as a single token.